# jQuery ~ How to check text in input value

Tags: jquery

When user type text a, b, c is ok.

If user type another text like 0, 9, z, x.... alert('can't type this word');

How to make it easily ?

Comment: The best way to achieve this is using regular expressions.

Comment: let me make it clear ... you have an input type text and you want to use jquery to test whether the entered value is ''a'', ''b'', or ''c'' and in other cases alert something?

Comment: You right Elwhis,would you mind show me the example?

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#yourInputId").keyup(function() {
     if($(this).val() == "z") {
        alert("You cant type this");
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: ^^ good, but if user type over one word,like 'azbc',how to check it??

Comment: @user962408, `if(  $(this).val().match(/[^abc]/) ) {alert("unallowed characters");}`

Answer (score 1):

This is the link to allow [Number and not alphabets](http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/L98tW/) (check the code here and make changes)....
Help your self finding out the key code for whichever alphabet you need to allow...
[Here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) is the keycode

Answer (score 1):

You can try use regular expression. example:
http://www.9lessons.info/2010/01/jquery-validation-with-regular.html

or setup a powerful plugin like:
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/